# Confusion with Ellipsis in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook, ellipsis

```
In [81]: a
Out[81]: [[...]]

In [82]: b
Out[82]: [[Ellipsis]]

In [83]: a==b
Out[83]: False

In [84]: ...==Ellipsis
Out[84]: True
```

Why it is that when Ellipsis are in lists they are not equal, and when they are by themselves they are equal?

Comment: `[[...]] == [[Ellipsis]]` is true. It's probably because `a` issues `...` because of the representation.

Comment: How did you create `a` and `b`?

Comment: `a` was created like this: `a=[1];a[0]=a` and `b` was created like this: `b=[[Ellipsis]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that

```
>>> [[...]] == [[Ellipsis]]
True
```

but

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[<Recursion on list with id=70796424>]
>>> print(a)
[[...]]
>>> a==[[Ellipsis]]
False
>>>
```

which is expected because you're comparing the `Ellipsis` object with an ellipsis representation of a recursively defined list.